# Not able to use EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".login" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      android:text="@string/username"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="text" >

      <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
      android:text="@string/password"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPassword" >
      <requestFocus />
      </EditText>

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
      android:onClick="login"
      android:text="@string/Login" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
      android:text="@string/attempts"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
      android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above code, I am trying to make a basc login page. But, somehow I am always getting the following error whenever I use EditText:-

The following classes could not be found:
- EditText (Change to android.widget.EditText, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Please help me out

```
import java.lang.Object;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class login extends Activity {

   private EditText  username=null;
   private EditText  password=null;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.login );
      username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   public login(View view){
      if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && 
      password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, article.class);
      startActivity(intent);
   }    
   else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);   
      counter--;
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      if(counter==0){
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

   }

}


}
```

Comment: did you `import android.widget.EditText` in you code?

Comment: do xml files need `imports`

Comment: @Ruthvik are you trying to add EditText statically or dynamically

Comment: can you please post your Activity code ?

Comment: I posted my activity code above.. I did import android.widget.EditText

Comment: Please do help me out with this problem!!

Answer (score 0):

it may be happening because you are using `request focus` two times in your xml design just remove one of it and then run your code hope it will help you

just **copy paste** my **below code** hope it will solve your problem happy coding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".login" >

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
      android:text="@string/hello_world"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      android:text="@string/username"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="text" >

      <requestFocus />
   </EditText>

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
      android:text="@string/password"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPassword"/ >



   <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
      android:onClick="login"
      android:text="@string/Login" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
      android:text="@string/attempts"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
      android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did try to do it with one request focus... It gave the same error. Just in case, I copy pasted ur suggested code too, same error. Please do let me kno if der is anythin else I cud do. Infact even when i put one edittext, it gave me error.